# What does '...paths.js' mean in ' gulp.src([...paths.js, '!gulpfile.babel.js'], { base: '.' }) '?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6

I have the following gulp task:

```js
// Compile ES6 to ES5 and copy to dist
gulp.task('babel', () =>
  gulp.src([...paths.js, '!gulpfile.babel.js'], { base: '.' })
    .pipe(plugins.newer('dist'))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.babel())
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.', {
      includeContent: false,
      sourceRoot(file) {
        return path.relative(file.path, __dirname);
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

According to the Gulp Doc([gulp.src](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpsrcglobs-options))  I learnt that gulp.src
emits files matching provided glob or array of globs.
But I can't understand the meaning of  '...paths.js' here.
There is no file named with 'paths.js' in the project directory.

Is there anybody who can help me to understand it?

Comment: I knew the meaning of ... but I was just curious about paths.js in the Gulp task.

Comment: I assumed that it is a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`...` in that context is ES2015 (aka "ES6") [*spread* syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator): It takes the content of an iterable (like an array) and spreads it out into discrete elements in the array.

Example:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [...a, 4, 5];
console.log(b); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

So

```
gulp.src([...paths.js, '!gulpfile.babel.js'], { base: '.' })
```

...is creating a new array with the contents of `paths.js` followed by `'!gulpfile.babel.js'` and passing that array into `src`. I'm assuming `paths.js` is an array; if so, in this particular case it could be replaced with `concat`:

```
gulp.src(paths.js.concat('!gulpfile.babel.js'), { base: '.' })
```

---

You can also use spread syntax in function calls:

```js
function testing(a, b, c) {
  console.log("a = " + a);
  console.log("b = " + b);
  console.log("c = " + c);
}
let x = [1, 2, 3];
testing(...x);  // Shows:
                // a = 1
                // b = 2
                // c = 3
```

Comment: Could you tell me what path.js do here ?

Comment: @ColinWitkamp: `paths.js` is presumably defined somewhere in your gulpfile, most likely as an array of paths to JavaScript source files.

Comment: Ah, I see! I found the following snippet: const paths = {
  js: ['./**/*.js', '!dist/**', '!node_modules/**', '!coverage/**'],
  nonJs: ['./package.json', './.gitignore'],
  tests: './server/tests/*.js'
};

Comment: Thanks for your answer!